# Cakephp: How to pass value from dropdown in View to controller index query

Tags: cakephp

I am really new to MVC and I am trying to do really simple thing in CakePHP - I think I do not understand the whole idea.

I have this dropdown in my View:

```
            echo $this->Form->create('dropdown');

            echo $this->Form->input('Sezon', array('options' => $seasons, 'empty' => '(Sezon bieżący)')); 

            echo $this->Form->submit();

            $selected_value = $this->request->data['dropdown']['Sezon'];

        ?> '
```

And I would like to pass this $selected_value variable to my controller, so that it displays data according to the value selected, this is my controller code:

```
public function index() 
{
require 'SeasonsController.php';
$seasons = new SeasonsController();
    $this->set('results', $this->result->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Result.season' => $selected_value))));

}
```

But this doesn't work - I keep getting Undefined variable: selected_value error. What am I doing wrong? It must be something really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The index function normally wouldn't use the selected value.  You would normally use the selected value to view/edit a record.

In the index function you would normally retrieve a list of records from the table.  And the index view would display the list.

A drop down would normally be used in an edit function and view to update a field in a single record.

It is good to use bake to create the simple CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) functions and view and then update them to meet your requirements.